# Blue lines under images in hrefs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get some links into a footer so I've decided to start off by using  tags with svg images. However I have little blue lines under the icons.
I've looked up on the website and found that you were supposed to add this:

```css
.icon {
  width: 3%;
  height: 3%;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>
          <a href=" https://github.com/--/ ">
          <img src="images/github.svg " class="icon" >
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/--/ ">
        <img src="images/linkedin-logo.svg " class="icon" >
      </a></li>
        <li><a href="files/--.pdf ">
        <img src="images/home.svg " class="icon" >
      </a></li>
      </ul>
```

I am not sure what else to add to possibly remove these little lines!
Any ideas?

[Here is a picture of what I am seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSGdy.png)

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Your live demo isn't very useful. The HTML is missing. You need an [mcve] (and an actual question)

Comment: Add your `text-decoration:none` on your `a` elements

Comment: "I've looked up on the website" — Which website?

Comment: can you please share link for test?

Comment: @MayurDusane — Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: add in style `text-decoration:none`

Answer (score 0):

Links have an underline by default.

You need to set `text-decoration: none` on the *links* not on the images inside them.

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

NB: Globally removing the link markers isn't a great idea. You could write a more specific selector that just targets the image links.